# How can I remove alarm when user delete event?

Tags: android, events, alarmmanager

I am adding an event to my schedule
   list and alarm has been fixed to that
   event. I have to     repeat alarm for
   every one minute, from the before five
   minutes of event ending time. In below
   conditions I have to remove or cancel
   alarm for particular event.

1. When I delete event from my schedule.
2. Event placed in schedules but I don't want alarm for event.

I am following concepts like sqlite database, Alarm manger, Services. I am confusing little bit using Services and pendingIntent. So, please suggest me the right way to approach my requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the method `cancel(...)` from `AlarmManager`, using the same `PendingIntent` you used to set the alarm. Example:

```
this.getAlarmManager().cancel(mAlarmPendingIntent);
```

(`this` refers to the `Activity` or the `Service` from which you are cancelling the alarm).

Here is the [link for the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Create the PendingIntent as:

```
mAlarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, flags);
```

The API doc for PendingIntent is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

Comment: for particular event how can i get pending intent..in the case when i delete event from my schedule list